# stock prediction data visualization

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, data-analysis

I want to get data from excel file and visualize it with `matplotlib`.
The data is stored as `(date , price)` but the date is daily and I want to get it monthly.
How do I get the data to be monthly?

my code is

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")
plt.plot(data['Date'],data['price'])
```

and data

> ```
> Date         Price
> 27-Nov-2017   20
> 28-Nov-2017   30
> 29-Nov-2017   40
> 30-Nov-2017   50
> 01-Dec-2017   60
> 02-Dec-2017   70
> 03-Dec-2017   80
> 04-Dec-2017   10
> 05-Jan-2017   3
> 06-Jan-2017   17
> 07-Feb-2017   90
> 08-Feb-2017   55
> ```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please proofread and properly format your questions.

Comment: You need to extract the month from your `Date` column. Look into `str.split()` in Pandas docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to format the date column, then calculate the needed stats. Something like this should get you started.

```
data = pd.read_csv("ex.csv", parse_dates=[0])
data.groupby(data['Date'].dt.to_period('M'))['Price'].agg(['sum'])
```

Comment: thanks, but how can split to 2 columns for plotting ?

Comment: `data = data.groupby(data['Date'].dt.to_period('M'))['Price'].agg(['sum']).reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to calculate the mean, or average, price for each month and plot that. The question becomes, do you want the highest price for each month? Or the lowest? I assume the mean.

Comment: i have more excel files with more data and 'Different Dates not arranged ' so i can't calculate every prices for month cause i don't know 'when month will start and end'